# Programmatically show link to another report in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a grouping in my report that I want to use to link to another report. My dilemma is that I only want the link to be clickable when the value in the cell fulfills a certain criteria (number > x for example). If the condition isn't true, then I don't want the cell to be clickable. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I've tried to set an `IIF` statement as part of the url, but what do I link to in the "false-part" of the statement? Using `""` actually just refreshes the report, which isn't really what I want either. It also complains when I tried `about:blank` saying the url must start with `http://` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Nothing keyword in iif expression as false part. If Nothing is specified for Action than no link will be created.

```
=iif(YOUR_CONDITION, "Other Report", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

An action isn't dynamic so there's no way to turn it on and off based on a condition. But the expression you use to open another report can use an expression - whether you are using jump to report or the jump to URL action. One thing you might consider is for the condition when you don't want to jump to the other report is to jump to the same report. That is, let's say you are on Report A and you want to jump to Report B only when number > x. Then you use the expression:

```
=iif(number > x, "Report B", "Report A")
```

Report A will be cached so the net effect is that you didn't click even though the user can see the cursor change to a hand and can in fact execute a click.